# JAUS++ library setup

Tags: c++, g++, jaus++

I installed the [JAUS++](http://active-ist.sourceforge.net/jaus++.php?menu=jaus) (version 2.110519) on my 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 system following the provided instructions. The installation went fine (no warnings were thrown), but upon attempting to compile tutorial_01 (found below), g++ is unable to find the jaus libraries. I tried a number of solutions such as setting environment variables, including libraries, linking to libraries, etc. but have had no luck in getting the sample program to compile. What am I doing wrong?
Below is one attempt that I made (I feel like this is the closest to what I need to do)

```
g++ -L /usr/local/lib/active -o tutorial_01 tutorial_01.cpp
```

Below is tutorial_01.cpp

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///  \file tutorial_01.cpp
///  \brief This file is part of a set of tutorials for learning how to use
///        JAUS++.  This program demonstrates how to create and initialize
///        a JAUS component with the Core Service Set.
///
///  <br>Author(s): Daniel Barber
///  <br>Created: 3 July 2010
///  <br>Copyright (c) 2010
///  <br>Applied Cognition and Training in Immersive Virtual Environments
///  <br>(ACTIVE) Laboratory
///  <br>Institute for Simulation and Training (IST)
///  <br>University of Central Florida (UCF)
///  <br>All rights reserved.
///  <br>Email: dbarber@ist.ucf.edu
///  <br>Web:  http://active.ist.ucf.edu
///
///  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
///  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
///      * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
///        notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
///      * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
///        notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
///        documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
///      * Neither the name of the ACTIVE LAB, IST, UCF, nor the
///        names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
///        derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
///
///  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE ACTIVE LAB''AS IS'' AND ANY
///  EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
///  WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
///  DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL UCF BE LIABLE FOR ANY
///  DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
///  (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
///  LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
///  ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
///  (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
///  SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <jaus/core/component.h>
#include <cxutils/keyboard.h>
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// Create a component.  By default a component
// has all the services of the Core Service set:
// - Transport (JUDP)
// - Control
// - Discovery
// - Events
// - Liveness
// - Time
// - Management
JAUS::Component component;

// The Transport service is used to send
// and receive messages to other JAUS components.  All
// other services use the Transport service.  The
// default transport type for JAUS++ is UDP communication
// using the JUDP class.

// The Discovery service is used to find
// other JAUS components and services on the
// network using the Transport service.  In JAUS++
// Discovery will automatically find these components,
// make connections to them, and keep track of what
// services they have.

//  The first thing we must do for a component is
//  configure its identification.  This is done by
//  using the Discovery Service.  Get a pointer
//  to the service:
JAUS::Discovery* discoveryService = NULL;
discoveryService = (JAUS::Discovery*)component.GetService(JAUS::Discovery::Name);
//  Alternative method:
//  discoveryService = component.DiscoveryService();

// Set the type of subsystem the component is for.  Subsystem
// types available are currently Vehicle, or OCU.  The string
// name "Robot" represents the type or category of platform.
// You must set the subsystem identification before you will be
// able to initialize your component.
discoveryService->SetSubsystemIdentification(JAUS::Subsystem::Vehicle,
                                            "Robot");
// You can also set identification information for the component
// and node that it is on.
discoveryService->SetNodeIdentification("Primary Computer");
discoveryService->SetComponentIdentification("Baseline");

// Now that we have setup our identification information we
// can initialize our component.  First, create the
// component ID.
JAUS::Address componentID(1000, 1, 1);
// Initialize!
std::cout << "Initializing component...";
if(component.Initialize(componentID) == false)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize component [" << componentID.ToString() << "]\n";
    return 0;
}
std::cout << "Success!\n";

// Now go into your main computer loop until the
// component has been told to shutdown.
JAUS::Time::Stamp displayStatusTimeMs = JAUS::Time::GetUtcTimeMs();
while(true)
{
    // Let's check the "state" of our component. This
    // is done using the Management service. 
    // A component can be in the following states:
    // - Initialized
    // - Ready
    // - Standby
    // - Shutdown
    // - Failure
    // - Emergency
    JAUS::Management* managementService = NULL;
    managementService = (JAUS::Management*)component.GetService(JAUS::Management::Name);
    // Alternative method:
    //managementService = component.ManagementService();
    if(managementService->GetStatus() == JAUS::Management::Status::Shutdown)
    {
        // Exit program.
        break;
    }
    if(JAUS::Time::GetUtcTimeMs() - displayStatusTimeMs > 500)
    {
        std::cout << "======================================================\n";
        // Print status of the service.
        managementService->PrintStatus(); std::cout << std::endl;

        displayStatusTimeMs = JAUS::Time::GetUtcTimeMs();
    }

    if(CxUtils::GetChar() == 27)
    {
        break;
    }

    CxUtils::SleepMs(1);
}

// Shutdown your component completely.  Any
// services added or belonging to the component
// will be deleted.
component.Shutdown();

return 0;
}



/* End of File */
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be just a typeo, but I believe the -L option should not have any whitespace after it:

```
g++ -L /usr/local/lib/active -o tutorial_01 tutorial_01.cpp
```

should be

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib/active -o tutorial_01 tutorial_01.cpp
```

May not be the problem, but it's worth a shot!